# What is wrong with this line? Php concatenation error

Tags: php, string, codeigniter, concatenation

I have error on this line:

```
$previous_next = '<div class="previous">POPRZEDNI WPIS:<h4><a href="#">'.<?= $previous_row->title ?>.'</a></h4><br></div>';
```

The error is

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered

Type: ParseError

Message: syntax error, unexpected '<'

Filename: E:\XAMPP\htdocs\projekt2\application\models\Devloger.php

Line Number: 68

Backtrace:

File: E:\XAMPP\htdocs\projekt2\application\controllers\Main.php
Line: 9
Function: model

File: E:\XAMPP\htdocs\projekt2\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

Sublime Text even doesn't highlight this code properly.
But I can't see anything wrong in here.
What is wrong here?

Comment: `<?= $previous_row->title ?>` should be `$previous_row->title` You have not use `<?` inside php-code

Comment: To add to the comment above; The error is being thrown because you are already inside of the php tags, there's no need to add another set of `<?= ?>` when you're already inside a pair.

Comment: just remove the PHP tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$previous_next = '<div class="previous">POPRZEDNI WPIS:<h4><a href="#">'.$previous_row->title.'</a></h4><br></div>';
```